# How to compare field data with another

Tags: javascript

I have a php form that gets validated through javascript. I would like to add another field to the form where the user has to confirm their email. How can I do this in the javascript validation file please?
Here is my current validation for the initial email form:

```
this.setHandler('email',
        function (value) {
            regex=/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,4}$/;
            return regex.test(value);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt something like this...

```
this.setHandler('email-confirm',
    function (value) {
        return value == document.getElementsByTagName('email')[0].value;
    }
);
```

Assuming your *confirm email*'s `name` (or whatever the first argument to `setHandler()`) is `email-confirm`, and the original email input's `name` is `email` (and assuming it is the first element of such).

Basically, I'm comparing the current value of the `email-confirm` to the original value, and if they are equal, the function returns `true`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you explain what the above code does so I get a better understanding please?

Answer (score 0):

Of course the real answer is be careful when writing a regex to validate email, as most people get it wrong. Yours ignores the first part for something like myname+other@domain.com as well as failing for [custom top-level domains](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/).

If you can, use an existing library like [jquery-validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), because they have already done the hard work for you and have built-in email validation as well as field comparisons.

If you need to write it yourself, use a [better expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript).

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

Anyway, you actually asked on how to "confirm" their email...which isn't it just a matter of comparing one field against another.

```
// using jQuery
this.setHandler('email2',
    function (value) {
        return (value == $("#email").val());
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. What does the above code do then? When I say confirm, I mean to confirm that the user has typed in the right email address and not made a mistake. Surely all it would need to do for that would be to compare the original email field with the new confirm-email field?